# SSRS data labels repeating same count across charts

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, reporting, label

I am working on a SSRS report on tests that shows the changes in scores for multiple tests. The chart is hooked up to one Dataset attached to a stored procedure . Each chart is for different tests, however the data labels are repeating the counts for the first test.  I would post a sample image, but I don't have a 10 reputation. 
 I know this has to be simple, but I am missing it altogether.

Comment: Is the chart correct except for the labels? If so, then you'll want to check out the Series Label Properties' **Label Data** expression. Usually you would use the value for the label. You might have an expression that uses the first value. Click on the label and check the **UseValueAsLabel** property in the Properties window.

Comment: Thanks for your Hanover! Yes it is correct except for the labels. That sounds like what the problem is.